# How to determine what file extensions my PHP environment will parse

Tags: php

On a standard Unix LAMP installation, how can I determine what file extensions will be parsed by PHP?

I'm thinking in terms of shared hosting environments such as GoDaddy, Hostgator, etc... Where LAMP is already installed and root access is not provided. When logging into an unfamiliar environment, how can I determine what file extensions will be parsed by PHP by default?

Is there any "master list" that just shows what extensions PHP or is preconfigured to parse? Or rather which extensions Apache will send to PHP to be parsed?

Comment: are you able to get file name

Comment: I don't think there's an *easy* way to get this information. Apache alone gives you multiple ways to configure this. It can even change from directory to directory (think .htaccess).

Answer (score 2):

If using Apache, take a look into its `httpd.conf` file.
All extensions listed in "`AddType application/x-httpd-php`" will be send to the PHP interpreter (usually looks like "`AddType application/x-httpd-php` .`php` `.phtml`")

Answer (score 1):

If you can't access these configuration files because your limited by the hosts permissions.  You could try the brute force way.  Place a file on your server, in (usually 'public_html' or 'www') with each one of the extensions you suspect will work with a little piece of code like.

```
<?php 
echo phpinfo();
?>
```

If the server returns actual info on your server then that works.

Remember to delete these files after use, dumping phpinfo() to the world is a security risk.